# C++ crash after inserting number

Tags: c++

Implement in C ++, using a personal library, an application that determines based on the choice made by the user if a number is positive or negative or if a number is prime or not.

So, i made the application and it works, but everytime i insert the number to see if the number is prime or not, it just crashes. Can you help me? There aren't any errors.
The application:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libreria.cpp"

using namespace std;

int s,num, cont=0, resto, k;;
void copyright();
int main()
{
    copyright();
    cout<<"\n 1) Positive ";
    cout<<"\n 2) Prime ";
    cout<<"\n 3) Exit ";
    cout<<"\n Choose: ";

    do
    {
        cin>>s;
        switch (s)
        {
        case 1:
            cout<<"\nInsert the number: ";
            cin>>num;
            if (sepos(num) == 1)
            {
                cout<<"\nIl numero "<<num<<" is positive";
            }
            else 
            {
                cout<<"\nIl numero "<<num<<" is negative";
            }
        break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"\nInserisci il numero: ";
            cin>>num;
            seprimo(num, resto, cont, k);
            if (cont == 2)
            {
                cout<<"\nIl numero "<<num<<" is prime";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"\nIl numero "<<num<<" isn't prime";
            }
        break;
        }
    } while (s!=3);
    return 0;   
}
```

And here's the library:

```
bool sepos(int numb)
{
    if(numb >= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
int seprimo(int numb, int resto, int cont=0, int k=1)
{
    while (k <= numb)
    {
        resto=numb%k;
        if( resto == 0)
        {
            cont = cont + 1;
        }
        k = k + 1;
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Comment: …….. why are you including `.cpp` files?

Comment: Because my professor wanted me to include a custom library, the one I attached.

Comment: You probably want a `.h[pp]` and `.cpp`, then only include the `.h[pp]` file. That would more likely be what the professor meant by a library.

Comment: But this is weird because, even if i include the .cpp file, the application tells me if the number is positive or negative, so i don't think that's the problem...

Comment: Oh, no, it's not the problem. Sorry, should have prefixed that with "off-topic".  It's just bad form/style.

Comment: What do you observe when you run this program through your debugger?

Comment: `seprimo(num, resto, cont, k);` In this line, `k` is not initialized, so `while (k <= numb)`, could run any number of times. Not sure which compiler you use, but g++ and clang you should turn on `-Wall`, and MSVC is `/Wall` (I think)

Comment: Oh, ok Chris, thanks for the tip. When i run the program through my debugger it just crashes. I think the problem is related to the calculation in the function  "int seprimo", but i don't understand what is wrong with that.

Comment: @anastaciu, where? It's a default value of 1 if it's not provided, but it's not initialized in `main`, unless I'm blind?

Comment: @ChrisMM, my mistake, I saw the parameter initialization but didn't check the main function, it's a rather unusual technique that threw me off :) Sorry about that.

Comment: @anastaciu, No worries, I was questioning my eye sight for a minute. Wouldn't be the first time I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
resto = numb % k;
```

As `k` becomes `0` it will cause a floating point exception, witch is unhandled, hence the crash.

Try to run this:

```
cout << 5 % 0;
```